# {a^nb^n} union {a }is deterministic or not

Tags: union, automata, context-free-language

I am confused according to me it should not be deterministic as there will be states for (a,zo/azo) going to q1 and (a,z0/eplison) going to final state. Is this true or not

Comment: Possibly a better question for the math exchange site. This is a more theoretical question, and StackOverflow tends towards the more practical side of computer science.

Comment: a^nb^n is a a non regular language and can not be expressed using a finite state machine. You need a push down automata (or Context Free Grammar). As both can be expressed as context free grammars and context free grammars are closed under union, then the result is a context free grammar.

Comment: Beoliver deterministic cfl is not closed under union so acc to that its union should not be deterministic. And its not deterministic. Am i right??

Comment: you are right @simranjitsingh